# PHP/MySQL - any shorthand equivalent for PDO UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of moving to PDO from mysql_query and am struggling to find a more concise way to write what is currently:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET session = '$session'  WHERE email='$email'");
```

The standard PDO equivalent seems to be this:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET session = :session WHERE email = :$email");
$sth->bindParam(':session', $session);
$sth->execute();
```

This introduces 2 new lines of code and having to type 'session' 4 times instead of 2 for this example. I'm not impressed! Is there are quicker way to write this?

Comment: [Deal with it.](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lSikG-cbzuY/UEsp0guujMI/AAAAAAAACpE/0Hd3pJjsVvk/s1600/oprah-deal-with-it.gif) Either you use an unsecure, deprecated function or write a few extra lines to write it correctly.

Comment: It's worth it. Unless you're ok with SQL injection.

Comment: You could always write a wrapper class that has a `query()` method; arguments would be something like `$pdo->query($sqlQuery, $arguments);`... your wrapper could execute the necessary steps and you could always access it through a single-line (if that's what is "clean" to you)

Comment: Write a wrapper that you call e.g. PDOUpdate($query, $parms[]) and in there loop through the parms and use bindparam on it. 
That's the only way I have found of shortening it

Comment: 3 new lines) you forgot about `:email`

Comment: It's not a few extra lines when you have hundreds of these statements, it's hundreds of extra lines.

Comment: there is `bindParams` Why need you hundreds variables in your query?

Comment: I mean across a site there are hundreds of SQL statements, this all amounts to an increase in code and an increase in typing that code.

Comment: No! Write your own wrapper in one place, and call it ever...

Comment: What do you mean, I'm talking about different statements not the same one.

Comment: see here: https://github.com/vpArth/om/blob/master/server/core/db/DB.php It's not a perfect, I share concept only...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can omit the `bindParam` calls by putting an array of parameters in the call to `execute`:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET session = :session WHERE email = :email");
$sth->execute(array(':session' => $session, ':email' => $email));
```

I don't like it much, but if you don't want to have to write "session" and "email" so many times, you could use positional parameters instead of named ones:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET session = ? WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute(array($session, $email));
```

Comment: Also, if you want it a bit shorter, you can use unnamed parameters:

`$sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET session = ? WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute(array($session, $email));`

Comment: I just added that while you were posting the comment

Comment: Ok that's not looking to bad, it's the re-typing of session and e-mail  that was the niggle.

Comment: You could save even more characters by using `[ ... ]` instead of `array( ... )`.